# 'X' and 'Z' difference in Fortran 77 when representing for hex

Tags: fortran

I am working on some legacy code. I saw two kinds of Integers:

```
z'ffffffff' and 'ffffffff'x
```

from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/c4000413626f/index.html
X or Z are for hexadecimal. So what's the difference between `z'ffffffff' and 'ffffffff'x`?

Comment: Note none of those were in the FORTRAN 77 standard, although `O'digits'` and `Z'digits'` (at left only) were in MIL-STD-1753, which was implemented by practically all F77 implementations and thus in fact portable. The other forms are extensions that were developed by various vendors, possibly years earlier, that Sun implemented to increase the saleability of its hardware in the 1980s. If you want to know about the vendors who created (or used) various extensions I think that belongs on retrocomputing.SX instead.

Comment: See also https://stevelionel.com/drfortran/2020/08/11/doctor-fortran-in-were-all-bozos-on-this-bus/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both were accepted as compiler extensions by the (pre-Fortran 90) compiler that was used to compile your code.

In Fortran 90 and later only the `z'0000'` syntax is allowed. The standard revision differ in the context where exactly they are allowed to be placed.

The `'0000'x` is completely non-standard.